# SAPIEN PowerShell Studio - Open child window without locking parent window

Tags: powershell

In SAPIEN PowerShell Studio, how can I open a child form such that the parent form can still be used?

I would like a user to be able to open a child form and move it to the side and continue working.

The code I have treats the child form as a popup such that you have to close the child form before working with the parent form again.

```
# Inside parent form
  $openChildForm_Click = {
  Show-ChildForm_psf
}
```

Comment: This sounds like something you should ask on the product forums.  Do they implement WPF? WinForms?  It's a bit too open-ended.

Comment: Here is their support forums area: https://www.sapien.com/forums/

Answer (score 1):

Good question as I have asked myself the same.... You could always just create a completely separate EXE in PS Studio and call that EXE as your action. That would make them both usable. Not a preferred method but would work.